# How to change Title of a HTML button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to Change the title of a HTML button once clicked. this is what I tried.

**HTML**

```
<button class="fullScreen" data-dojo-type="dijit.form.Button" onclick="FullScreenToggle(this);" id="butFullScreen">
<input type="image" class="ns" onclick="FullScreenToggle(this);" title="Full Screen" value="" />
```

**JS**

```
if (document.getElementById("butFullScreen").title == "Full Screen") {
    document.getElementById("butFullScreen").title = "";
    document.getElementById("butFullScreen").title = "Normal Screen";
} else document.getElementById("butFullScreen").title = "Full Screen";
```

When I do this Title doesn't change in JavaScript call. then I tried using `title=""` in HTML, then title changes on Java Script call. but when button is loaded first time I dont have a title. I want have  Full Screen as title when button is loaded and then toggle it between Normal Screen & Full Screen on each click.

Once I set title="Full Screen" in my HTML, a JavaScript call doesn't change it.

Comment: Side note: this HTML snippet is not valid since you aren't closing the `<button>` tag. While browsers are designed to fix invalid HTML, there's no guarantee that all browsers will apply the same fixes. Producing 100% valid HTML will save you some headaches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u need to call a function onload site
Execute a JavaScript when a page is finished loading:

In HTML:

```
<body onload="FullScreenToggle();">
```

In JavaScript:

```
window.onload=function(){FullScreenToggle();};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
if (document.getElementById("butFullScreen").getAttribute('title')=="Full Screen"){ 
   document.getElementById("butFullScreen").setAttribute('title',"Normal text");
    }
else
   document.getElementById("butFullScreen").setAttribute('title',"Full Screen");
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I have set title="Full Screen" in HTML code. it doesn't change on Java Script call :(

Comment: Well the thing is once I set title="Full Screen" in my HTML, java-script call doesn't change it. I there any solution or reasoning for that?

Answer (score 3):

try this 
In button Click:

```
 var butn=document.getElementById("butFullScreen").value;
 if(butn=="Full Screen")
     document.getElementById("butFullScreen").value="Normal Screen";
 if(butn=="Normal Screen")
     document.getElementById("butFullScreen").value="Full Screen";
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer, but Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. I have set title="Full Screen" in HTML code. it doesn't change on Java Script call.

Actually I want to change the Title(title can work as a tooltip), not the value.

Comment: The title attribute of a button is the *tooltip*, not the displayed text.

Answer (score 2):

Give title to your button:

```
function FullScreenToggle(){
 if (document.getElementById("butFullScreen").title == "Full Screen"){
    document.getElementById("butFullScreen").title = "Normal Screen";
 } else {
    document.getElementById("butFullScreen").title = "Full Screen";
 }
```

Comment: Tried, but no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

My preference would be to make only 1 `document.getElementById` call for cleanliness and ease of maintenance. Also, I would use the `.title` attibute directly.

```
function FullScreenToggle() {
    var button = document.getElementById("butFullScreen");
    if (button.title == "Full Screen") {
        button.title = "Normal Screen";
    } else {
        button.title = "Full Screen";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

<sub>OP's solution migrated from the question to an answer:</sub>

> [I] kept the `title=""` as blank, and called the JavaScript method in the `<body onload>` method and it worked.